# Doesn't find my main class in a jar

Tags: java, class, exception, jar, program-entry-point

I'm developing a program with three classes and also includes some external jar archives and classes. When I run it in Eclipse it works properly, but I need to try with some other programs, so I need to run it at the console. I save all of it in a folder, which contains another two folders, one with the .class created by me and the other one with the .java and .jar archives and a folder with the external classes. I've tried to creat a .jar archive containing this folder and the manifest, where I told where's the main class.

When I run it I receive "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError", so it doesn't found the class where the main is, but I don't know why. I've tried some different ways to define it at the manifest and changing the classpath and it still doesn't work.

Any solutions or advices?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post:

- the command you use to create the Jar
- the command you use to run the program
- the stacktrace when it fails (i.e. the full error message when you see `Exception in thread "main"`, etc)

Comment: It looks to be a familar situation for me. How does your startscript look?

Comment: It seems that find your main, but throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, can add some of the stacktrace?

Comment: The stacktrace is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /bin/TextClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .bin.TextClient
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: /bin/TextClient. Program will exit.

Comment: I use "jar -cmf manifest.txt Server.jar Server" to create the jar,being Server the folder with all the archives. I run it with "java -jar Server.jar"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice), it will let you define the main class.

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the file existed during compile time, but it was not found during run time. Since there were no compilation issues, the jar was created, but at run time, while using command like java -jar jarfilename fullyqualifiedclassname it threw this exception. Check the classpath variable, validate that you are executing the command from the right folder location in command window.
I had always referred the below link for such errors and it worked for me

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

when creating a project for example ABC the IDE normally Netbeans creates the source folder and creates the main class as ABC.java which contains the main class. In Netbeans IDE let you mention your main class if it is not ABC or if not you must create an instance of the class you want to run when application executes in ABC.java class.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I ran also in the same situation. The problem was always a missunderstanding of mine with this error message.

The reason **in my case** was that the computer could not found the declared jar file. The use of the parameter `-cp` let me became happy. So try

```
java -jar -cp ./Server.jar
```

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I had also to mention the full qulified name of class which contains the main class.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
The stacktrace is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /bin/TextClient
```

looks to me like your Manifest is wrong. To correct it, you can use:

```
jar -uvfe Server.jar full.name.of.your.MainClass
```

Note: **not** the file/path name of some class file!
This will create a MANIFEST that tells that `full.name.of.your.MainClass` is your main class.

In addition, if your jar contains entries like:

```
bin/Foo.class
bin/...
```

you created the JAR file probably from the wrong place (unless your TLD is bin).
If your main class is named `org.adepts.Main`, then a top level entry should be:

```
org/adepts/Main.class
```

(This is where it will be searched.)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by using the Eclipse "Export" option and not creating it manually.